# Springdata/JPQL -- How to put in element from list to subselect value

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, jpql

Spring Data / JPQL problem
base: posgresql 10
backend : Java / Spring boot

I have a very interesting problem,
how can I insert the currently selected value from the java list used in where as the value for the subselect.

Some pseudocode

Data to select 
code:

Data for the select comes from the object

```
List<DateForSelect> listOfElements;

@Data
public class DateForSelect {

    private Long idDoc;    
    private Long additionalValForSelect;

}
```

---

```
select sp.xd, (subselect value from actual pair of element list of object "additionalValForSelect") from xx.sport sp where sp.doc_id in :idDoc
```

any ideas for solving this problem without FUTURE PROCESSING IN JAVA

I will add that I know how to mapp this query this later. I am just wondering how you can eventually pull out the current value of the idDoc element and associate it with additionalValForSelect as the value of the subselect.

```
Synature of sql init repository method : 
List<CustomMapp> searchXD(
      @Param("idDoc") Collection<Long> num);
```

is it possible in jpqlu in the form of subselect. Non-JPQL solutions are not interesting, eg Native Query.

if you have interesting ideas without code examples, please give inspiration: D

pseudo sql code:

```
SELECT p.sth,'additionalValForSelect[0]' as tmp FROM  schemat.tabelka p where p.id= 'idDoc[0]'
union 
SELECT p.sth,'additionalValForSelect[1]'   FROM  schemat.tabelka p where p.id= 'idDoc[1]'
union 
SELECT p.sth,'additionalValForSelect[2]'   FROM  schemat.tabelka p where p.id= 'idDoc[2]'
union 
SELECT p.sth,'additionalValForSelect[3]'   FROM  schemat.tabelka p WHERE p.id= 'idDoc[3]'


for ..... loop ...
```

number of unions = listOfElements.size (its still pseudocode)

Comment: If you can show me the SQL statement I can tell you how you can implement it with JPQL .

Comment: https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-element-collection-demo/   ElementCollection, CollectionTable found sth but . there is still a problem because I can only add fixed values.
And the list ... can accept different input values ​​each time.
It is not possible to add them all to the dictionary.
Unless you can replace directly before asking in some session that only the user sees. I do not know, this is a good direction I'm going to. @SimonMartinelli

Comment: add pseudo sql to post. @SimonMartinelli

Comment: hello :D  anybody here :D

Comment: Unfortunately there is no UNION in JPQL. Ever thought to use plain SQL?

Comment: it does not necessarily have to be union. maybe other ideas. I just wanted to avoid spagetti in dynamic sql code: D @SimonMartinelli